# Momentum probability density from Wigner distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wigner-transform

[image]I want to prove that $|\hat{\psi}(p)|^2= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int W_\psi \mathrm{d}x $ where $W_\psi $ is the Wigner function.
Starting with the definition I get ($z=-y$ and $u=x+z/2$):
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint \psi^*\left(x-\frac{y}{2}\right)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}py} \psi\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right) \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x= \frac{1}{2\pi}\iint \psi^*\left(u\right)\psi\left(u-z\right) \mathrm{d}u\: \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}pz}\mathrm{d}z$$
Next I want to use the Convolution Theorem to get the product of the Fourier Transforms:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\iint \psi^*\left(u\right)\phi\left(z-u\right) \mathrm{d}u\: \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}pz}\mathrm{d}z= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathcal{F}(\psi^{*}*\phi)(p)=\hat\psi^*(-p)\hat{\psi}(-p) $$
But with the definition $\phi(x):=\psi(-x)$ I get $|\hat{\psi}(-p)|^2$. Does somebody know where the problem is?

Comment: Your exponent on the left hand side has a  very ***wrong sign*** ! This amounts to a *p* flipped around....

Comment: @CosmasZachos in the first line?

Comment: On the left hand side of the first line. You are mis-defining *p*.

Comment: @CosmasZachos but is $W_\psi(x,p)=\int\psi^*\left(x-\frac{y}{2}\right)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}py} \psi\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right) \mathrm{d}y $ not the definition of the Wigner function?

Comment: Of course not. Where did this come from? Certainly not Wigner or a reputable text.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have added the definition from the exercise sheet

Comment: I think it is pretty standard definition... up to insignificant coefficients: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution

Comment: @Roger Vadim . Absolutely not! If you flip the sign of *y*,  the exponent has the wrong sign. The OP is ***only*** asking about that wrong sign of p....

Comment: @CosmasZachos yes, indeed. I focused more on what I think is a somewhat convoluted approach they had taken.

Comment: @CosmasZachos it‘s from an exercise sheet but for me there‘s nothing wrong with the definition. In units where $\hbar=1$ it differs only by the normalization which should make no difference for this exercise.

Comment: You don't understand: This is the definition of the Wigner function in a phase-space where the *p* axis is flipped to *-p*, which is what you correctly find. The sign of the exponent matters, and what you have defined there, dysfunctionally, is the Wigner function $W(x,-p)$. Your exercise sheet is inconsistent.

Comment: @CosmasZachos thank you. I'm not really familiar with the Wigner function so does that mean if I use the definition from Wikipedia I get the correct result?

Comment: If you use the WP definition you get the correct result; isn't it obvious?

Comment: @CosmasZachos ahh yes thanks. I didn‘t see that the WP definition has the plus sign in the complex conjugated wavefunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use
$$
\psi\left(x\pm\frac{y}{2}\right)=\int dx e^{ip\left(x\pm\frac{y}{2}\right)}\bar{\psi}(p)
$$
and
$$
\int dxe^{i(p-p')}=2\pi\delta(p-p')
$$